# Calculadora Javascript(Não retorna valor)

Tags: javascript, matemática, alert

Meu projeto de calculadora simples em javascript(Contendo alguns botoes),não retorna nenhum valor.
Mesmo com o alert nada funciona.

```js
function testResults (form) {
 var operacao= form.operacao.value;
 //entrada dados da primeira parte
 var num1 = form.num1.value;
 var num2 = form.num2.value;
 var num3 = form.num3.value;
 var num4 = form.num4.value;
 var num5 = form.num5.value;
 var num6 = form.num6.value;
 var num7 = form.num7.value;
 var num8 = form.num8.value;
 var num9 = form.num9.value;
 var num0 = form.num0.value;
 //entrada dados segunda parte
 var nnum1 = form.nnum1.value;
 var nnum2 = form.nnum2.value;
 var nnum3 = form.nnum3.value;
 var nnum4 = form.nnum4.value;
 var nnum5 = form.nnum5.value;
 var nnum6 = form.nnum6.value;
 var nnum7 = form.nnum7.value;
 var nnum8 = form.nnum8.value;
 var nnum9 = form.nnum9.value;
 var nnum10 = form.nnum0.value;
 var total1,total2,total3;
 //parte que soma os campos
 if (num1 == 1) {
  total1=total1+1;
 };
 if (num2 == 2) {
  total1=total1+2;
 };
 if (num3 == 3) {
  total1=total1+3;
 };
 if (num4 == 4) {
  total1=total1+4;
 };
 if (num5 == 5) {
  total1=total1+5;
 };
 if (num6 == 6) {
  total1=total1+6;
 };
 if (num7 == 7) {
  total1=total1+7;
 };
 if (num8 == 8) {
  total1=total1+8;
 };
 if (num9 == 9) {
  total1=total1+9;
 };
 if (num0 == 0) {
  total1=total1+0;
 };
 // parte soma segundo campo
 if (nnum1 == 1) {
  total2=total2+1;
 };
 if (nnum2 == 2) {
  total2=total2+2;
 };
 if (nnum3 == 3) {
  total2=total2+3;
 };
 if (nnum4 == 4) {
  total2=total2+4;
 };
 if (nnum5 == 5) {
  total2=total2+5;
 };
 if (nnum6 == 6) {
  total2=total2+6;
 };
 if (nnum7 == 7) {
  total2=total2+7;
 };
 if (nnum8 == 8) {
  total2=total2+8;
 };
 if (nnum9 == 9) {
  total2=total2+9;
 };
 if (nnum0 == 0) {
  total2=total2+0;
 };
 window.alert("Primeira variavel"+total2+"Segunda variavel"+total11);
 console.log("Variavel 1 ="+total1);
 console.log("Variavel 2 ="+total2);
 switch (operacao) {
  case "posi":
  total3=total2+total1;
  window.alert(total3);
  break;
  case "subt":
  total3=total2-total1;
  window.alert(total3);
  break;
  case "mult":
  total3=total2*total1;
  window.alert(total3);
  break;
  case "divi":
  total3=total2/total1;
  window.alert(total3);
  break;
  default:
  window.alert("Erro: Selecione uma operacao");
 };

};
```

```css
.butao1{
 margin-top:10%;
}
.butao2{
 margin-left:55%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Calculadora</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="titulo">Calculadora</div>
  <form method="GET" action="">
   +<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="posi">
   *<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="mult">
   -<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="subt">
   /<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="divi">
   <div class="butao1">
   <input type="radio" name="open">
   0<input type="checkbox" name="num0" value="0">
   1<input type="checkbox" name="num1" value="1">
   2<input type="checkbox" name="num2" value="2">
   3<input type="checkbox" name="num3" value="3">
   4<input type="checkbox" name="num4" value="4">
   5<input type="checkbox" name="num5" value="5">
   6<input type="checkbox" name="num6" value="6">
   7<input type="checkbox" name="num7" value="7">
   8<input type="checkbox" name="num8" value="8">
   9<input type="checkbox" name="num9" value="9">
   </div>
   <div class="butao2">
   0<input type="checkbox" name="nnum0" value="0">
   1<input type="checkbox" name="nnum1" value="1">
   2<input type="checkbox" name="nnum2" value="2">
   3<input type="checkbox" name="nnum3" value="3">
   4<input type="checkbox" name="nnum4" value="4">
   5<input type="checkbox" name="nnum5" value="5">
   6<input type="checkbox" name="nnum6" value="6">
   7<input type="checkbox" name="nnum7" value="7">
   8<input type="checkbox" name="nnum8" value="8">
   9<input type="checkbox" name="nnum9" value="9">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" onclick="testResults(this.form)">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apesar de todos os outros problemas, o seu erro tá sendo causando no seu ultimo if (nnum0 == 0). Você declarou var nnum10 = form.nnum0.value; 

É só mudar o nnum10 para nnum0.

Não vou usar isso como resposta, e sim comentário pq tem muitos outros problemas nesse seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Tente substituir teus names por IDs, e faça a recuperação do valor assim:

```
HTML:
<input type="checkbox" id="num1" value="1">

JAVASCRIPT:
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
```

Depois de ajustar para todos as tags no formulário e no javascript, você só precisará adaptar para sua lógica.

Sugiro depois dar uma olhada em JQUERY, vai te economizar um tempão no seu código e fica mais fácil também

Answer (score 0):

youboll, tem bastante coisa incorreta em seu código.

Corrigindo algumas variáveis que não foram declaradas, como a **nnum10** e a **total11**, existiam alguns erros nas validações (IF), por fim, inicializei as variáveis de soma com zero, pois como elas não tinha valor inicial, era gerar um **NaN** durante o cálculo.

Você estava pegando o valor do checkbox e efetuando uma verificação de igualdade, essas validações sempre era verdadeiras, por mais que o checkbox não estivesse marcado, portanto alterei esses trechos para apenas verificar se o checkbox está marcado, somando assim os valores.

Após essas correções de variáveis e condições, a sua calculadora funcionou, mas ainda cabe uma grande refatoração!

Deixei alguns comentários no código pra orientar melhor as alterações que fiz, veja também que fiz um *return false no onsubmit*, isso foi feito para evitar que ao clicar a página seja redirecionada, pois formulário assim com submit não é o ideal para uma aplicação de calculadora.

```js
function testResults(form) {

  var operacao= form.operacao.value;

  //O checkbox já tem o valor correto, portanto a ideia é ver se ele foi marcado
  //entrada dados da primeira parte
  var num0 = form.num0.checked;
  var num1 = form.num1.checked;
  var num2 = form.num2.checked;
  var num3 = form.num3.checked;
  var num4 = form.num4.checked;
  var num5 = form.num5.checked;
  var num6 = form.num6.checked;
  var num7 = form.num7.checked;
  var num8 = form.num8.checked;
  var num9 = form.num9.checked;
  //entrada dados segunda parte
  var nnum1 = form.nnum1.checked;
  var nnum2 = form.nnum2.checked;
  var nnum3 = form.nnum3.checked;
  var nnum4 = form.nnum4.checked;
  var nnum5 = form.nnum5.checked;
  var nnum6 = form.nnum6.checked;
  var nnum7 = form.nnum7.checked;
  var nnum8 = form.nnum8.checked;
  var nnum9 = form.nnum9.checked;
  var nnum0 = form.nnum1.checked;

  //Inicializei as variáveis
  var total1 = 0;
  var total2 = 0;
  var total3 = 0;

  //Se for marcado, você faz a soma
  //parte que soma os campos
  if (num1) {
    total1=total1+1;
  }
  if (num2) {
    total1=total1+2;
  }
  if (num3) {
    total1=total1+3;
  }
  if (num4) {
    total1=total1+4;
  }
  if (num5) {
    total1=total1+5;
  }
  if (num6) {
    total1=total1+6;
  }
  if (num7) {
    total1=total1+7;
  }
  if (num8) {
    total1=total1+8;
  }
  if (num9) {
    total1=total1+9;
  }
  //Não faz sentido somar zero
  //if (num0) {
  // total1=total1+0;
  //};

  // parte soma segundo campo
  if (nnum1) {
    total2=total2+1;
  }
  if (nnum2) {
    total2=total2+2;
  }
  if (nnum3) {
    total2=total2+3;
  }
  if (nnum4) {
    total2=total2+4;
  }
  if (nnum5) {
    total2=total2+5;
  }
  if (nnum6) {
    total2=total2+6;
  }
  if (nnum7) {
    total2=total2+7;
  }
  if (nnum8) {
    total2=total2+8;
  }
  if (nnum9) {
    total2=total2+9;
  }

  //Não faz sentido somar zero
  //if (nnum0) {
  // total2=total2+0;
  //};

  window.alert("Primeira variavel: " + total1 + "\nSegunda variavel: "+total2);
  console.log("Variavel 1 = " + total1);
  console.log("Variavel 2 = " + total2);

  switch (operacao) {
    case "posi":
      total3=total2+total1;
      window.alert(total3);
      break;
    case "subt":
      total3=total2-total1;
      window.alert(total3);
      break;
    case "mult":
      total3=total2*total1;
      window.alert(total3);
      break;
    case "divi":
      total3=total2/total1;
      window.alert(total3);
      break;
    default:
      window.alert("Erro: Selecione uma operacao");
  }
}
```

```css
.butao1{
  margin-top:10%;
}

.butao2{
  margin-left:55%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="titulo">Calculadora</div>
    <form method="GET" onsubmit="return false" action="">
      +<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="posi">
      *<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="mult">
      -<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="subt">
      /<input type="radio" name="operacao" value="divi">
      <div class="butao1">

      <!--Não utilizado-->
      <!--<input type="radio" name="open">-->
      0<input type="checkbox" name="num0" value="0">
      1<input type="checkbox" name="num1" value="1">
      2<input type="checkbox" name="num2" value="2">
      3<input type="checkbox" name="num3" value="3">
      4<input type="checkbox" name="num4" value="4">
      5<input type="checkbox" name="num5" value="5">
      6<input type="checkbox" name="num6" value="6">
      7<input type="checkbox" name="num7" value="7">
      8<input type="checkbox" name="num8" value="8">
      9<input type="checkbox" name="num9" value="9">
      </div>
      <div class="butao2">
      0<input type="checkbox" name="nnum0" value="0">
      1<input type="checkbox" name="nnum1" value="1">
      2<input type="checkbox" name="nnum2" value="2">
      3<input type="checkbox" name="nnum3" value="3">
      4<input type="checkbox" name="nnum4" value="4">
      5<input type="checkbox" name="nnum5" value="5">
      6<input type="checkbox" name="nnum6" value="6">
      7<input type="checkbox" name="nnum7" value="7">
      8<input type="checkbox" name="nnum8" value="8">
      9<input type="checkbox" name="nnum9" value="9">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" onclick="testResults(this.form)">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```